# com.springsource.org.aopalliance Jar is missing from Nexus repository. Which Repository to add to get the same

Tags: spring, maven, nexus

I had tried adding Repository by using [this blog post](http://spring.io/blog/2009/12/02/obtaining-spring-3-artifacts-with-maven/).

But Still Not able to get the dependency http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/bundle/version/detail?name=com.springsource.org.aopalliance&version=1.0.0&searchType=bundlesBySymbolicName&searchQuery=com.springsource.org.aopalliance

Then I read ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/faq Which says that "The repository is frozen "
So Which repository should I configure to Nexus Server to get the mentioned jar and get the data.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find "com.springsource.org.aopalliance" either.
So I check the Spring's dependencies (its pom.xml, version 4.1) And I found the following:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
  <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

I almost sure Spring uses the same version of aopalliance for a while.

Comment: With this you're most probably using [aopalliance from Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|g%3A%22aopalliance%22). _com.springsource.org.aopalliance_ is two years younger. Are you sure SpringSource didn't add or modify something to/in their artifact?

Comment: I just inspect a recent Jar of Spring from Maven Central (http://tinyurl.com/lqcwj84). So when I get Spring from Maven Central, I get this (old) version of aopalliance. I cannot help more.